# How to get multiple inserted identity values in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am inserting values in to the table `QueryList`

```
    [QueryID] [WorkItemID] [RaisedBy]
       1        123           xyz
       2        234           abc
```

where `QueryID` is an `Identity` column.

I am using a `foreach` loop and inserting more than one value at a time. My question is how to get all the newly inserted `Identity` values in Entity Framework 3.5

This is my code

```
using (TransactionScope currentScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    Query newQuery = new Query(); 
    foreach (long workItemId in workItemID)
    {
        newQuery = new Query();
        ...

        currentScope.Complete();
        success = true;           
    }
 }
 entityCollection.SaveChanges(true);

 int  QueryID = newQuery.QueryID; //It gives me last 1 Identity value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to track each newly created `Query` object separately. I suggest using a `List<Query>` for simplicity:

```
using (TransactionScope curentScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    List<Query> newQueries = new List<Query>(); 
    Query newQuery = new Query();
    newQueries.Add(newQuery);
    foreach (long workItemId in workItemID)
    {
        newQuery = new Query();
        newQueries.Add(newQuery);
        ...
        curentScope.Complete();
        success = true;           
    }
}
entityCollection.SaveChanges(true);

var queryIDs = newQueries.Select(q => q.QueryID);
```

*Side note*: In your code sample you created a `Query` object outside of the for-loop, but didn't use it at all. This may just be because it's just a sample, but if you use it or insert it in your data context, don't create it.

Comment: Of course - you're right - too early in the morning here :-) Brain isn't up to speed yet. .... :_)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. its working fine. curentScope.Complete();
should come outside the foreach loop